# Is it safe to use Polly retry to handle HTTP request errors for longer time intervals

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, thread-safety, polly

I trying to implement my own version of WebHooks for my application. When a user registers their URL hook (assume its wrong URL or will not respond with 2XX code), i would like to retry up to five times in an custom exponential interval say 5 mins, 30 mins, 2 hrs, 4 hrs and 16 hrs. I have implemented this using .NET Polly library.

My question is,

1) In worst case is it safe to extend up to 16 hrs for 5th retry?

2) Is it thread safe (Polly says it is thread safe as long as my code is thread safe) but my concerns is 16 hrs long intervals.

3) Say 10 requests are failed and all the requests are retrying in their own interval. So, increasingly more requests are failed after some time does my server thread pools will become full and unable to accept any new requests?

4) Due to long intervals is it really worth using Polly like libraries or better go for CRON job schedulers?

My implementation details are very similar or identical to Polly's official example `IHttpClientFactory` ([link](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#using-polly-with-ihttpclientfactory)).

Thanks for you suggestion.

Comment: You may find this interesting: [Fire and Forget on ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly encourage you to deep dive into the Polly source code, it's relatively easy to read.

From example if you start from the `WaitAndRetryAsync` function you will shortly reach the `AsyncRetryEngine`. This contains the retry implementation, that's why it's only method called `ImplementationAsync`. If we jump to the [wait related part](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/ffe99a34edd96d5c5c94075fe22aae8e1a7ed3ed/src/Polly/Retry/AsyncRetryEngine.cs#L74) then you will find there the following piece of code:

```
if (waitDuration > TimeSpan.Zero)
{
      await SystemClock.SleepAsync(waitDuration, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext);
}
```

If you look at the `SystemClock` then you will find the `Sleep` and `SleepAsync` fields (methods) definition:

```
public static Func<TimeSpan, CancellationToken, Task> SleepAsync = 
   new Func<TimeSpan, CancellationToken, Task>(Task.Delay);

SystemClock.Sleep = (Action<TimeSpan, CancellationToken>) ((timeSpan, cancellationToken) =>
  {
    if (!cancellationToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(timeSpan))
      return;
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  });
```

As you can see if you call the `WaitAndRetryAsync` then your policy will call the `Task.Delay`, which is non-blocking. If you call the `WaitAndRetry` then your policy will call the `WaitHandle`'s `WaitOne`, which is blocking.

So if you use WaitAndRetry for that long period then that will block the thread (unless it is terminated for some reason). In case of WaitAndRetryAsync the ThreadPool will receive the notification about completion after the Delay completed.

---

But still I would suggest to use cron jobs for this sort of problems.